# Pass bandwidth of backing light for LCD display

Tags: lcd, display, uv, pixels

A stardard industry LCD display is composed of several parts. Polarizer film and color filters produce and image by masking the light from a source positioned behind the LCD itself, the so called backlight.

Many resin 3D printers today use an LCD display to actively mask an UV source, used as backlight, by selectively turning on / shutting off pixels.
I read that the fact that a UV source is used compromises the lifetime of the display, since UV light slowly damages the display, shortning its life to circa 500 hours of operation

Normally the UV backlight used in 3D printing has a wavelength of 405 nm. Will it work with shorter wavelength? Proving of course that a resin which reacts to shorter wavelengths is available.
I saw resins available for 385 nm, but what about using even shorter wavelengths?

Comment: what is unclear? The LCD display is used as an active mask for 3D printing. A UV light source is used instead of standard LED backlight. The source normally has a wavelength of 405 nm. Will it work with shorter wavelengths?

Comment: "what is the bandwidth of the backlight that can be used" is it unclear maybe?

Comment: it asked that, now just modified the question to make it more readable

Comment: Absorption will increase as you lower wavelength, requiring higher power and further accelerating damage to the LCD.

Comment: I know this. But how big portion of the UV light will actually be transmitted? And how much will.be absorbed?

Comment: Shorter wavelengths are more energetic and will cause more damage, not less. For example UVC 200-280 will kill germs, and 405nm (on the edge of UVA to visible) will not.

Comment: @Francesco We don't even know what panel you're using. How could anyone answer that question?